# Automated Crossfade between two AUX tracks

Tags: pro-tools

I have 2 aux tracks, all set to output to the main output bus.
The source input for all of these aux tracks is a single track - basically the track out is being routed to all these two aux tracks via unique buses.

```
* Source track output -> Aux1,Aux2
* Aux1 -> Main Output
* Aux2 -> Main Output
```

I want to be able to use volume automation to fade between the 2 auxiliary tracks seamlessly without any resultant change in the overall level of the output. Unfortunately adding a linear automation fade at the right spot does not do the trick as this causes a volume dip across the automation fade. This is due to the visual representation of the automation fade not being representative of an actual audio edit.

At the mid-point of the automation fade (from 0dB to -inf dB) the fader level should (ideally) be 3 dB down so that there can be a seamless "crossfade" between these two channels.

Unfortunately at the mid-point of the fade the volume level is actually -19dB down on both aux tracks, resulting in a dip at the mid-point of approximately 16dB.

The requirement for the solution is for the mid-point of the fade to be 0dB down for a crossfade of at least 1 second.

If there is a "butt" edit (i.e. immediate level change) then the switching between Aux tracks can be achieved, however I need to be able to do this over a longer timeframe than 0 seconds... ideally 2-3 seconds.

The reason for this requirement is to be able to seamlessly switch between different noise-reduction configurations across a master as it is not possible to store and manipulate noise profiles within the automation engine.

How do I do this?

Comment: I might not fully understand the question but could you link the 2 aux buses as stereo and automate the pan?

Comment: Actually, that is possibly worth a try. It all boils down to how the automation that is rendered on-screen translates to dB values in the mix engine. It might be possible to do this using front-to-back panning. I'll let you know how this 'pans' out (sorry)

Comment: I admit that was a good one haha

Comment: Getting closer to a solution this. My problem is that I now need to down-mix a Quad track to Stereo by discarding the rear channel pair or routing it nowhere. Thwarted at every turn on this! Yup - just as I thought - there is no downmixer available for quad to stereo :-(